# Critique and redesign: Change template for a philosophical website

Tags: website-design, critique, website-templates, contrast, template-design

**Please help me in designing the review and critique of this page**

I am a programmer, and a designer gave me an image of a webpage. I made it and everything is OK, but I don't like this template's **folders** and **article** icon design.

and this is my template:

[image: rifae]

This is **picture of folder** icon:

[image: folder Icon]

and This is **article icon**:

[image: article Icon]

---

When a user clicks on the **folder icon**, the website shows the **sub folder** of that folder, *like all operating systems*

I think the icons (folder icon, article icon) should be designed as **Philosophical** and **islimi**(Arabesque).

A screenshot of the page when I click on the folder icons is shown below (sub folder):

[image: ajax reloading template]

all of the folders have some sub folders too.

> and please suggest me a good color for folder icon and article icon to have contrast with template

Comment: For sub folder, why don't you create a and image of a folder "creeping" out of another folder?

Comment: thanks @SaturnsEye, can you show me how is that? i can't understand

Comment: @Kermani So you are looking to change the design of the icons so they have a more Arabesque Style to them? Is that all?

Comment: Yes
And I plan to be philosophical because it is philosophically website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a VERY rough idea just for your `sub folder` situation:

[image]

I know you don't like the original design of the folder itself but you could apply  a similar method as I've done here to your final folder design to emphasize the folder being a "sub" folder of another.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, can you please suggest me a good color too

Comment: @Kermani It really depends what colours you want to use. May I suggest using [Kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/) to help give you better ideas on matching up colours to work better with each other.

Comment: I need a color to have contrast with whole template and be comfortable